Vector field with almost non-periodic orbits
Let $M$ be an n-dimensional smooth manifold (Open or compact). I want to know if it is possible to construct an smooth vector field with exactly one singularity, such that the set of periodic integral curves has null n-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
Any reference/idea is appreciate.
